# Как посмотреть вывод postgres в ответе jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Есть sql запрос, который через callable statement отправляется в постгрес, в этом запросе есть raise notice, благодаря которому после исполнения запроса в постгресе показывается вывод со значениями, которые были сгенерированы самим постгресом. Вопрос в том, как посмотреть этот вывод через ответы jmeter, если в респонсе только:
`0 updates. Output variables by position:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы вызываете хранимую процедуру через [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)  и [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)  - можно использовать функцию [Statement.getWarnings()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings()) которая возвращает первый выхлоп RAISE

если вы используете обычный [JDBC Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) - такой возможности из коробки нет.